# Unable to run multiple Pipelines in desired order by creating template in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have two separate Pipelines say 'P1' and 'P2'. As per my requirement I need to run P2 only after P1 has completely finished its execution. I need to get this entire operation done through a single Template.

Basically Template gets created the moment it finds run() its way say p1.run().

So what I can see that I need to handle two different Pipelines using two different templates but that would not satisfy my strict order based Pipeline execution requirement.

Another way I could think of calling **p1.run()** inside the ParDo of **p2.run()** and keep the run() of p2 wait until finish of run() of p1. I tried this way but stuck at IllegalArgumentException given below.

> java.io.NotSerializableException: PipelineOptions objects are not serializable and should not be embedded into transforms (did you capture a PipelineOptions object in a field or in an anonymous class?). Instead, if you're using a DoFn, access PipelineOptions at runtime via ProcessContext/StartBundleContext/FinishBundleContext.getPipelineOptions(), or pre-extract necessary fields from PipelineOptions at pipeline construction time.

Is it not possible at all to call the run() of a pipeline inside any transform say 'Pardo' of another Pipeline?

If this is the case then how to satisfy my requirement of calling two different Pipelines in sequence by creating a single template?

Comment: I dont think dataflow is the right thing to do what you asked. You should have a look at workflow managers like luigi or airflow

Comment: Or maybe create 2 different pipelines, call them from different module so they execute one after another. But again you need to make sure that  the first job doesnt fail

Comment: @anuj Tried the second approach as well !!! created two different modules and called them from a different class in my desired sequence by creating a template of the caller class. Again the jobs failed stating some IllegalArumentExceptions which can be concluded that this way also we can't achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Yes, I did mention that already. The thing is, data flow isn't built to do things in a way workflow manager program would do! You could look into Luigi which is actually a python based workflow management system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template can contain only a single pipeline. In order to sequence the execution of two separate pipelines each of which is a template, you'll need to schedule them externally, e.g. via some workflow management system (such as what Anuj mentioned, or Airflow, or something else - you might draw some inspiration from [this post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) for example).

We are aware of the need for better sequencing primitives in Beam within a single pipeline, but do not have a concrete design yet.

Comment: Thank you. It was very convincing. I will look forward to explore some workflow management systems for the same.

Comment: In 2020, do we have better sequencing primitives yet?

Comment: In 2023, do we have better sequencing primitives yet?